# Model formulation: a conclusion about the model before solving it

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mathematical-modeling

I have found this simple model in a paper discussing robust optimization [1]

$$\max \vec{c}^{T}\vec{x}$$

s.t.
$$\sum_j a_{ij}x_j + \sum_j \tilde{a}_{ij}y_j \leq b_i \;\;\;\forall i$$

$$ -y_j \leq x_j\leq y_j \;\;\;\forall j$$

$$\vec{l} \leq \vec{x} \leq \vec{u} $$

$$\vec{y} \geq 0$$

$a_{ij}$ and $\tilde{a}_{ij}$ are such that they form an interval $[a_{ij}-\tilde{a}_{ij}, a_{ij}+\tilde{a}_{ij}]$ (but I don't know whether it is relevant to what follows).

Let $\vec{x}^{*}$ be the optimal solution. The authors state "*At optimality, **clearly**, $y_j=|x_j^{*}|$*". Unfortunately, I am not able to understand this conclusion. Would you please help me understand?

Thanks

[1] Bertsimas, Sim, 2004, The Price of Robustness. Operations Research

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the reformulated constraint $\sum_j a_{ij}x_j + \tilde{a}_{ij}|x_j| \leq b_i$ is binding at optimality, a proof is easy (there is simply no other $y_j$ that is feasible). The conclusion is erroneous otherwise (although the solution remains optimal if you let $y_j = |x_j|$).

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, since it is a maximization problem under a budget constraint, the original constraint (involving $\vec{y}$) should be binding at optimality. Further, since the objective involves only the $\vec{x}$ I would set $\vec{x}$ "as large as possible" and $\vec{y}$ to $0$, but this is prevented by the second set of constraints where $\vec{y}$ is greater than $\vec{x}$. So, the best solution is to set $\vec{x} = \vec{y}$. Is this a correct reasoning? Still, I miss the absolute value.

Comment: @Libra maximization vs minimization is irrelevant (as you can always multiply $c$ with $-1$). If the objective causes the constraints to be binding (which can be with an "as small as possible" (negative) $x$ as well (depending on the sign of $a_{ij}$)), your reasoning is correct.